Multiple Profiles in pom.xml do not build into multiple jars
I have the following project structure
root_project
|
+-- pom.xml
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
    <modules>
+-- A 
    |
    +-- pom.xml
        |
        +-- <profile><id>xml</id>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>....includes only xml files and excludes class files</profile>
        +-- <profile><id>ejb</id>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>....includes all class files and excludes xml</profile>
+--B
    |
    +-- pom.xml
        |
        +-- <dependency>A</dependency>

In the root folder, if I run mvn clean build, all works well.
In the root folder, if I run mvn clean build -P xml the ejb profile does not build the jar at all. Hence project B gives errors.
And I have tired the following to debug the issue further

Make build profile activeByDefault=true
     +-- <profile><id>xml</id>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>....includes only xml files and excludes class files</profile>
     +-- <profile><id>ejb</id>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>....includes all class files and excludes xml</profile>



Still only the xml profile is built, the ejb is not built, hence project B gives errors.

If I exchange the id names of the profiles, still only xml is build, and ejb is not.
+-- ejb
true....includes only xml files and excludes class files
+-- xml
true....includes all class files and excludes xml

Ideally mvn clean install -P xml,ejb should build both, but only xml gets built no matter what I tried.
Questions

How to get the pom to build both profiles, via cmd line
How to get pom to build both profiles, via parent module instruction

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Below are the actual profile sections below
  <profile>
        <id>ejb</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>ejb</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.MF</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>XmlDir/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <finalName>EJBFileName</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>12.2.1-3-0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>src/XmlDir/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin> -->
                <!-- <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>2.1</ejbVersion>
                        <includes>
                            <include>somefiles</include>
                            .. more includes ..
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>somefiles</exclude>
                            .. more excludes
                        </excludes>

                    </configuration>
                </plugin> -->

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


            </plugins>

        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- To generate xmlFile.jar -->
    <profile>
        <id>xml</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <build>
                <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/XmlDir</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName> xmlFile</finalName>
                        
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.dtd</include>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>src/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78616760/multiple-profiles-in-pom-xml-do-not-build-into-multiple-jars I am trying this solution out. Will update once I have tried it out.

Make separate modules for each purpose xml, jar etc. Easier following convention over configuraiton. Profiles are the wrong way...

Im also thinking, just seprate the project modules.. profiles is painful..

Done sorted it using separate projects.. 5 mins vs 3 hours of investigation..

Learnt a few things along the way.

Profile needs us to run the build multiple times to make multiple jars
Easier to just separate the code into different modules
And includes/excludes dont work in the <plugin> like they work in <build>
variable <packaging.type>jar</packaging.jar> is important to mention in <properties></properties>

